# Magento 2 change buttons order in the shopping cart page

Tags: magento2, blocks, shopping-cart

I need to change the order in the shopping cart page, I want to add **Checkout with Multiple Addresses** above the **- OR -** text like the following image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to know:

- Paypal button is in layout: `vendor/magento/module-paypal/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml`
- The multi Address checkout link is in layout `vendor/magento/module-multishipping/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml`

We can move the multi address checkout link:

*app/design/frontend/{Vendor Theme}/{Theme Name}/Magento_Multishipping/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="checkout.cart.methods.multishipping" destination="checkout.cart.methods" before="bml.center.logo"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Read more: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_rearrange